# how to get the description inside the popup when i click on marker in a map

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

I have 2 tables and i have mentioned the fields of it,
1. events:event_id,title,location,latitude,longitude,address,description,link
2. event_time:event_id,start_time,end_time,start_date,end_date,date

i have given the my map code below in that i am trying to get the popup when the particular marker is clicked on the map.when i click on the marker it displays the popup and in popup we retrieve the table datas.
The problem what i have is, i am able to get all the data from database other than description. but when i try to retrieve description the map wont be shown.
the way data is retrieved from the database is also given below in the code.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><script language="javascript">
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var markersArray = [];
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 500,

 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
     if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup =null;

 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;

 });
  google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {

  currentPopup.close();
  currentPopup = null;
 });
 }

 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.972352762582736,77.59734949737549),
 zoom:60,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });
 <?

$query=mysql_query("select * from events join event_time on (events.event_id=event_time.event_id) where events.isapproved='Y'");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
 $title=$row['title'];
 $location=$row['location'];
 $sdate=$row['start_date'];
 $edate=$row['end_date'];
 $stime=$row['start_time']; 
 $end_time=$row['end_time']; 
 $lat=$row['latitude'];
 $lon=$row['longitude'];
 $address=$row['address'];
 $date=$row['date'];
 $de=$row['description'];
 $link=$row['link'];
 echo ("addMarker($lat,$lon,'$stime ".to."$end_time<br/><br/><b>$title</b><br/><br/>$address<br/><br/>$de<br/><a>$link</a>');\n");
 }
 ?>

 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }
 </script>
```

the map code and retriveing data and displaying it are together.
if anyone knows it,please help me solve this problem.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the values for Description in your database. Are any characters which are Javascript special values escaped?

For instance, suppose the Description value for one record is:
      You can't find a better party than this one!

If you put this in place of $de in your addMarker line above, and leave all the other variables alone, the resulting line of Javascript is:

```
addMarker($lat,$lon,'$stime to $end_time<br/><br/><b>$title</b><br/><br/>$address<br/><br/>You can't find a better party than this one!<br/><a>$link</a>');
```

Notice that the apostrophe in "can't" now ends the Javascript string.  What the Javascript interpreter sees is code like:

```
addMarker($lat,$lon,'$stime to $end_time<br/><br/><b>$title</b><br/><br/>$address<br/><br/>You can'
t find a better party than this one!<br/><a>$link</a>');
```

The first line is an incomplete statement, and the second line starts with the second part of the $de value outside of quotes.

In general, almost all your variable values will be interpreted first as Javascript and then as HTML.  Thus, you should escape them according to HTML conventions and then Javascript conventions, in order to be sure they don't disrupt anything.